# Nesting (this) in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below examples, when `.article` has a class of `.has-video-thumb`, I want the `.video-bg <video>` to play.

The code below shows a working and non-working version. Within the nested `mouseenter` function, if I explicitly specify `.article`, it works as expected, however if I try to re-use `(this)` within the nested `mouseenter` function, it doesn't work and responds with a console error of 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined'.

Why does `(this)` not work in this instance?

**Not Working**

```
if ($('.article').hasClass('has-video-thumb')) {
    $(this).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find(".video-bg")[0].play(); // Console error shown
        }
    });
}
```

**Working**

```
if ($('.article').hasClass('has-video-thumb')) {
    $(this).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $('.article').find(".video-bg")[0].play(); // Working!
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what the *first* `this` refers to. The if statement on the first line does not set the value of `this` in any way.

Comment: @JJJ - perfect, thank you very much!

Comment: I'm guessing you actually want `$('.article.has-video-thumb').on(...`

Comment: Absolutely, thanks @JJJ - if you want to convert this into an answer I'll happily mark as correct. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JJJ for help with this one.

When using the `if` statement on the opening line, the value of `this` is not set in any way. We actually don't need to add an `if` statement, but simply change the first `this` to the element class names, which in this case is `.article.has-video-thumb`.

```
$('.article.has-video-thumb').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find(".video-bg")[0].play();
    }
});
```